# How to add custom (or outdated) attributes to styled-components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, xhtml, styled-components

I'm developing tool for making newsletters. That means I need to use lots of outdated HTML4/XHTML1 tags and attrs. For example, I want to create an element like this:

```
<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="%some css here%">
...
</table>
```

My stack is React 17, styled-components v5.3.3 and typescript v4.5.5.

#### Styled components definition:

```
interface ITable {
  align?: string,
  cellPadding?: number,
  cellSpacing?: number,
  border?: number,
  width?: string,
}

export const SCTable = styled.table.attrs(({ cellPadding = 0, cellSpacing = 0, border = 0, align, width }: ITable) => {
  return {
    cellPadding,
    cellSpacing,
    align,
    width,
    border,
  }
})<ITable>`
`;
```

#### Usage:

```
<SCTable width="42%" align="center"></SCTable>
```

#### Result:

```
<table width="42%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="..."></table>
```

As you can see only 3 of 5 attrs were added. I've checked [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html) about this and React doesn't support `align` and `border` attrs, but at the same time

> You may also use custom attributes as long as they’re fully lowercase.

Also there are some [issues](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_table.asp) with `table` tag in HTML5, because `border` attr is deprecated (but `align` is only not supported, as `cellPadding`). Switching doctype to XHTML have no effect.

Any thoughts how to make all attrs to appear in element? Replacing them with CSS won't help in case of opening result markup in some email clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. Outdated props were filtered by styled-components, and you can override this filter with `shouldForwardProp`:

```
const SCTable = styled.table
  .withConfig({
    shouldForwardProp: (prop, defaultValidatorFn) => ['align', 'border'].includes(prop) || defaultValidatorFn(prop),
  })
  .attrs<ITable>(({ cellPadding = 0, cellSpacing = 0, border = 0, align, width }) => {
    return {
      cellPadding,
      cellSpacing,
      align,
      width,
      border,
    };
  })<ITable>``;
```